# C# convert functions naming convention

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I have a function that converts an object into nullable int:

```
public int? ToInt(object x) { ... }
```

Now I need another function that would return 0 instead of null if conversion is not possible:

```
public int ToIntSomeOtherName(object x) { ... }
```

What would be a good name for that other function ?
I know this seems trivial, but I'll be using these functions in many places and
a good naming convention would be a big plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `ToInt` is better for your second method:

```
public int ToInt(object x) { ... }
```

And you can rename the first one:

```
public int? ToIntOrNull(object x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

How about ToIntOrDefault?

It's a convention used by the IEnumerable interface (FirstOrDefault).

Comment: Int32 defaults to 0, not null. If you want to use the "default" term it should read ToNullableIntOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

The name of a method first and foremost should be something you (and your company or team) can recognize and understand.

However sometimes the names can grow unwieldy. I highly recommend using XML annotations to provide the proper documentation of what your method does:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an object to an int.
/// If conversion is not possible, a default int value of 0 is returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">Object to convert to int.</param>
public int ToInt_NotNull(object x) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ToZeroForNull` could be the name for your method.

Answer (score 0):

How about DefaultOrValue this will be like the equivalent name of String.IsNullOrEmpty

```
public int DefaultOrValue(object x)
{ 
  int? intconverted = ToInt(x);
  return intconverted.HasValue ? intconverted.Value : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly arbitrary, however I use ToInt if it needs to be an integer and AsInt if it can be null.  This parallels the language's use of the 'as' keyword. I also make these methods extension methods of 'object' which removes any pre-checking for types and nulls.  I would also recommend ToInt leveraging AsInt so you don't double down on the parsing logic.